# compling glibc: /glibc-2.7/w/elf/ld.so: No such file or directory

Tags: c, gcc, makefile, glibc

I have to install a software in the directory of the supercomputer center, but I cannot use sudo, root, even apt-get, yum... The software requires glibc2.7, so I have to manually install both gcc and glibc (since I cannot change the path for built-in gcc to find the glibc).

The gcc seems to be installed successfully:

```
[geosign@node117 ~/binutils/bin]$ gcc -v
Using built-in specs.
Target: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
Configured with: /public/home/geosign/software/gcc/configure -prefix=/public/home/geosign/gcc --with-gmp=/public/home/geosign/Gcc --with-   mpfr=/public/home/geosign/Gcc --with-mpc=/public/home/geosign/Gcc --with-ppl=/public/home/geosign/ppl --with-cloog=/public/home/geosign/ppl --enable-threads=posix CFLAGS=-I/public/home/geosign/ppl/lib:/public/home/geosign/Gcc/lib CPPFLAGS=-I/public/home/geosign/ppl/lib:/public/home/geosign/Gcc/lib CXXFLAGS=-I/public/home/geosign/ppl/lib:/public/home/geosign/Gcc/lib --enable-languages=c,c++,fortran --disable-multilib
```

Thread model: posix
    gcc version 4.4.7 (GCC)

However, when I use "make" to compile the glibc, it shows:

```
make[3]: Leaving directory `/public/home/geosign/software/glibc/elf'
gcc -B/public/home/geosign/binutils/   -nostdlib -nostartfiles -r -o /public/home/geosign/software/build/glibc/elf/librtld.os '-Wl,-(' /public/home/geosign/software/build/glibc/elf/dl-allobjs.os /public/home/geosign/software/build/glibc/elf/rtld-libc.a -lgcc '-Wl,-)' \
      -Wl,-Map,/public/home/geosign/software/build/glibc/elf/librtld.os.map
gcc -B/public/home/geosign/binutils/   -nostdlib -nostartfiles -shared  \
      -Wl,-z,combreloc -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,--hash-style=both -Wl,-z,defs -Wl,--verbose 2>&1 |  \
      LC_ALL=C \
      sed -e '/^=========/,/^=========/!d;/^=========/d'    \
          -e 's/\. = 0 + SIZEOF_HEADERS;/& _begin = . - SIZEOF_HEADERS;/' \
      > /public/home/geosign/software/build/glibc/elf/ld.so.lds
gcc -B/public/home/geosign/binutils/   -nostdlib -nostartfiles -shared -o /public/home/geosign/software/build/glibc/elf/ld.so           \
      -Wl,-z,combreloc -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,--hash-style=both -Wl,-z,defs   \
     /public/home/geosign/software/build/glibc/elf/librtld.os -Wl,--version-script=/public/home/geosign/software/build/glibc/ld.map     \
      -Wl,-soname=ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 -T /public/home/geosign/software/build/glibc/elf/ld.so.lds
/public/home/geosign/software/build/glibc/elf/librtld.os: In function `_dl_start_final':
/public/home/geosign/software/glibc/elf/rtld.c:290: undefined reference to `_begin'
/public/home/geosign/binutils/bin/ld: /public/home/geosign/software/build/glibc/elf/librtld.os: relocation R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined hidden symbol `_begin' can not be used when making a shared object
/public/home/geosign/binutils/bin/ld: final link failed: Bad value
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [/public/home/geosign/software/build/glibc/elf/ld.so] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/public/home/geosign/software/glibc/elf'
make[1]: *** [elf/subdir_lib] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/public/home/geosign/software/glibc'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

These sentences in Makefile of elf are:

```
$(objpfx)ld.so: $(objpfx)librtld.os $(ld-map)
    @rm -f $@.lds
    $(LINK.o) -nostdlib -nostartfiles -shared $(z-now-$(bind-now))  \
          $(LDFLAGS-rtld) -Wl,-z,defs -Wl,--verbose 2>&1 |  \
          LC_ALL=C \
          sed -e '/^=========/,/^=========/!d;/^=========/d'    \
              -e 's/\. = 0 + SIZEOF_HEADERS;/& _begin = . - SIZEOF_HEADERS;/' \
          > $@.lds
    $(LINK.o) -nostdlib -nostartfiles -shared -o $@         \
          $(LDFLAGS-rtld) -Wl,-z,defs $(z-now-$(bind-now))  \
          $(filter-out $(map-file),$^) $(load-map-file)     \
          -Wl,-soname=$(rtld-installed-name) -T $@.lds
    rm -f $@.lds
    readelf -s $@ \
      | awk '($$7 ~ /^UND(|EF)$$/ && $$1 != "0:" && $$4 != "REGISTER") { print; p=1 } END { exit p != 0 }'
```

This is how I configure glibc:

```
/public/home/geosign/software/glibc/configure --prefix=/public/home/geosign/glibc  --with-binutils=/public/home/geosign/binutils/ --enable-shared --disable-multilib
```

ldd ld shows:

```
[geosign@node117 ~/binutils/bin]$ ldd ld
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff163be000)
    libz.so.1 => /lib64/libz.so.1 (0x0000003fd1400000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x0000003fd0400000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x0000003fd0000000)
```

Thank you very much. There is really limited time for me, and I have spent a lot of days on it.

Comment: Can any body help me?

Comment: this looks, to me, that the directory path to the directory that is to contain the ld.so file is partially or completely missing.   That is where I would begin my research into the root cause of the problem.   While researching, be sure to look at the `permissions` at each level of the directory  and you 'may' need to run the make using the `sudo` capability

Comment: Thanks. However, I cannot use sudo on the supercomputer center...

Comment: It is a bug in glibc2.7 that has been reported. Change  ' -e 's/\. = 0 + SIZEOF_HEADERS;/& _begin = . - SIZEOF_HEADERS;/' \ ' to ' -e 's/\. = .*0)\+ + SIZEOF_HEADERS;/& _begin = . - SIZEOF_HEADERS;/' \ '

Answer (score 2):

Your immediate problem is this:

```
gcc   -nostdlib -nostartfiles -shared -o -mcmodel=large \
  /public/home/geosign/software/glibc-2.7/w/elf/ld.so ...
```

This tells GCC to create an output file named `-mcmodel=large`, instead of intended output file `/public/home/geosign/software/glibc-2.7/w/elf/ld.so`.

You didn't tell us how you've configured this GLIBC build, but I suspect you've used `-mcmodel=large` somewhere in `./configure` invocation. Don't do that, there is *no reason* to use `-mcmodel=large` when building glibc.

Comment: Thanks. I have updated some information which the mcmodel=large was delete when configuring. However, it still showed the same error.

Comment: @Amy You are *not* getting the same error, you are getting a different one (in the same place). You probably didn't clean up from the previous failed build. Try `make distclean; configure; make`, or just re-start building GLIBC from scratch (blow away the directory completely and recreate it, extract sources, configure; make).

Comment: Thank you very much . I have fixed it: it is a bug reported in glibc.